# help in writing script to mount external hard drives

Tags: applescript, external-disk

Using: MacBookPro (Retina, 15-inch Mid 2015) macOS HighSierra V 10.13.2; Internal HD has 250GB.

In order to save space in my HD-internal, I have 5 USB connected external disks which are for backups and storage of images, files, etc.

I like to eject these devices when I no longer am using the laptop. I often used to get warnings device(s) not properly ejected. So, to prevent any potential disk damage, I eject these using a script I found in the internet.

I haven't been able to find one script that will mount those devices. I am hoping some one here will assist me in creating this script.

BTW, It is my first time here; I'm a 77 yo with very limited talent in using these technologies and I will appreciate any help you send my way.

DP

Comment: First of all, you're 77 and want to write AppleScript?  That's awesome and it's great to see that you still have a desire to learn new things!  Next, I use an application named [Jettison](https://www.stclairsoft.com/Jettison/) to mount/unmount my external drives.  It's not free but the developer is very helpful and it works great for me.  There's a free trial available.

Comment: Thank you fsb for your answer. I Will try that app; I see they offer a 15 day free trial.  

Happy holidays

DP

Comment: If it works, please come back here and let me know.  I can add that as an answer to your question and that could help others with the same issue.